# Django: How to POST div element to views.py without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have been struggling with this problem for more than four days. I have looked at many documentations but nothing helped me. I am working on Django web application development. The problem is that I have to get the contents(i.e. text inside) of a div element through a form submit (submitted using a button). The catch is that the content inside div element is not fixed. It is initially empty, it changes and shows the info of the actions performed in the page.
I am trying to save those info into a list on the server side one-by-one. The ideal solution will be "**everytime I click save-info button and the info gets added to a list of info present in views.py (webpage not refreshed on button click)**"

I researched about posting div elements to server using JQuery and tried myself but could not be successful. Can someone please suggest how do I achieve the task?

My effort:

```html
    <form method="POST" id = 'notes_form' action="##" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div id="notes" cols="5" rows="2"></div>
        <input type="submit" id="note_btn_id" value="save info">
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#notes_form').submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var notesForm = $(this);
                var posting = $.post(notesForm.attr('action'),notesForm.serialize());
                
                posting.done(function(data){
                    console.log("SUCCESS");
                });
                posting.fail(function(data){
                    console.log("Try again");
                })
            });
        });
        
    </script>
```

**views.py**Complete view function:

```py
def annotate_view(request):
    try:
        request.session.clear_expired()
        
    except:
        print("Error clearing exp sessions")

    img_path =  request.session.get('img_path_loc') #prev session data
    
    data_pos = []
        
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("request method is POST")

        print("posted contents",request.POST)
        if request.POST.get("note_btn_id"):
            content = request.POST['notes']
            data_pos.append(content)
            print(f"Contents received**: {content}")

        
    return render (request, "workpage/testtemplate.html",{
        'image_locs': img_path, #show the data in page when rendered
        'data_pos': data_pos,
    })
```

Still the server side is unable to get the "notes" element. It shows error showing "notes" is not present( MultiDictKeyError). Moreover, if I comment out `request.POST['notes']`, the `if request.POST.get("note_btn_id"):` statement is always false. What should I do?

Comment: The best approach to achieve this behavior is to create an endpoint on Django backend (with `django rest framework` or with `django-braces` `JSONResponseMixin`) which lets you handle a JQuery Ajax call. I can elaborate the answer if this approach match your needs.

Comment: @danieltellez Please do explain. It doesn't matter the approach as long as I'm able to implement the said behavior successfully. The problem got me confused a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to achieve what I think you want with the `django-braces` and `Jquery` approach.

First, install `django-braces`. This library is a must in all my django projects, because it gives you few useful mixins, mainly related with permissions.

On `urls.py`:

```
path('post/asjson/', views.PostCreateAsJSON.as_view(), name='post-asjson'),
```

On `views.py`:

```
from braces.views import JSONResponseMixin

class PostCreateAsJSON(JSONResponseMixin):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Whatever you want to do to create the post.
        # You will have your data on request.POST
```

On your template, I don't think you really need a form. You are trying to get the content of a DIV when you do click a button, so, maybe you only need this:

```
<div id="notes">{{ current_content|safe }}</div>
{% csrf_token %}
<button id="note_btn_id">{% trans 'Save' %}</button>
```

If you add `{% csrf_token %}` anywhere in your template, you will have this hidden input displayed:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="your_csrf_token_value">
```

On your javascript file:

```
$( '#note_btn_id' ).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const csrf_token = $( 'input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]' ).val()
    const contents = $( '#notes' ).text()
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrf_token)
        }
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'your_PostCreateAsJSON_URL',
        data: {
            contents: contents
        },
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log('Here you could update your frontend if needed')
        }
    })
}
```

Maybe not the best way to use csrf_token, but it works for the example. You can take a look a more in depth explanation on [Django CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/).

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a go. As per my knowledge of Django, it's required to have a form to have POST/GET request, django retrieves only the elements bound to the form. That's why I enclosed the div element along with the button in hope of getting the values. "csrf token" is inside this form. Will the the value for const csrf_token will be 'the form-id'?

Comment: will you be able to suggest some useful resources which explains how to use JSONresponsemixin properly. I am using it for first time and referring to Django official documentation, a bit confusing. is there any other resource?

Comment: yes, you can find braces documentation on this matter [here](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other.html#jsonrequestresponsemixin).

Comment: What you are trying to do don't need to be resolved using forms. 
You have some operations on the frontend using javascript, and when the button is clicked, you want the server be aware. To do that, you can use an Ajax call.

This is easier to achieve your goal, IMHO.